# Does an ES6 shorthand exist for copying a subset of an object's properties into a new object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Consider the following object:

```
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5}
```

Is there a simple syntax for creating a new object that contains:

```
const obj2 = {a, b, d}
```

I'm aware that underscore & lodash have `.pick()`, but I'm hoping there's some kind of destructuring trickery that I may not be aware of.

Comment: I can't think of anything in ES6 that's more readable than doing it the old way—`const obj2 = { a: obj.a, b: obj.b, d: obj.d };`—though repeating `obj` so many times is not that nice.

Answer (score 8):

Concise one-liner in ES2015 is

```
const obj2 = (({a, b, d}) => ({a, b, d}))(obj);
```

It doesn't seem to be possible to avoid `{a, b, d}` tautology while keeping it compact at the same time.

Comment: Wow, I was all excited about using this ES2015 construct for the first time, but it's still not quite as elegant as I hoped. Oh well, maybe a future version. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelScheper That's why Lodash `_.pick` is still applicable. The answers in dupe question cover it all.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in two steps:

```
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5};
var {a, b, d} = obj;
const obj2 = {a, b, d};
```

If you don't want to pollute the scope,

```
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5};
const obj2 = {};
{
  let {a, b, d} = obj;
  Object.assign(obj2, {a, b, d});
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Rest parameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and create custom pick function like this

```js
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5}

function pick(object, ...p) {
  return p.reduce((o, e) => {return o[e] = object[e], o}, {});
}

console.log(pick(obj, 'a', 'b', 'd'))
```